# CURL is not working inside Wordpress docker container (apache image not FPM)

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, curl

I was trying local installation of wordpress official docker images (defacto image not the fpm).

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - D:/CODEARENA/wordpress/local_docker_vols/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - D:/CODEARENA/wordpress/local_docker_vols/wordpress:/var/www/html
```

I was able to access the wordpress installation from the host using

> http://localhost:8080

But the following curls is not working when i go inside of the wordpress container's terminal from docker-desktop

> curl http://localhost:8080
> curl http://wordpress:80

Can someone explain why this is not working ? I tired expose port too, not working.

Comment: Please share more details. What does "not working" mean? How is this problem related to PHP?

Comment: By "not working" i meant the url is not accessible and didn't provide any response. am not exactly sure whether it is a problem with PHP or wordpress or docker configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server in the container is listening at port 80. From inside the Wordpress container it therefore has to be `curl http://localhost:80` or `curl http://wordpress:80`. You might not see a response from curl because it does not follow redirects by default. Try `curl -L http://wordpress:80` to follow redirects or `curl -v http://wordpress:80` to see additional info on the request.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my container by adding the hostname to the command line that started my container.

e.g.

```
podman run /
    --detach /
    --name mycontainer --hostname myhost.fqn.whatever /
    --publish 10.1.2.3:8080:80 /
    --publish 10.1.2.3:8443:443  /
    --volume /containers/podman/wordpress/var/www/html:/var/www/html:Z  /
    docker.io/library/wordpress
```

this had the effect of adding myhost to /etc/hosts inside the container

Ideally this needs to be added to the docker file,but I am not an expert.

hope this helps